# Is any way to use Selenium WebDriver RC to test remote iPad/iPhone device?

Tags: ios, selenium, webdriver

I'm wondering if it is possible to run Selenium WebDriver test client on Windows platform (client) and having Selenium RC Server + browser on remote iOs device (server) ? Thus having tested real device. The only clue I have found is [how-setup-selenium-ios-devices](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-setup-selenium-ios-devices-ha-do) but it requires MAC PC instead of Windows because of xcode. Also I think the workaround is install VMware on windows 7 and install Mac OX on VM. But it seems clumsy to me. 
Thank you. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Is this not something you can accomplish with Appium?

Comment: Take a look at [ios-driver](https://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/).